# Optimize multiple comparison conditions

Tags: c#, optimization, range, comparison

My main code needs to compare an integer ASCII command and I wonder if there is a solution to optimize this.

I can send from '1' to '128' on the serial bus, and to reach the proper object, here is how I do:

```
// this is how I deal with the data sent on the serial bus 
int translateASCII(char requestBuffer[10]){
    char word[4] = {0};
    word[0] = (int)requestBuffer[0];
    word[1] = (int)requestBuffer[1];
    word[2] = (int)requestBuffer[2];
    int n = atoi(word);
    return n;
}

void interpreteASCII(int ascii){
    if (ascii > 0 && ascii < 33){
        if (ascii < 9){
            blabla
        }
        else if (ascii < 17){
            blabla
        }
        else if (ascii < 25){
            blabla
        }
        else
            blabla
    }
    else if (ascii < 65){
        if (ascii < 41){
            blabla
        }
        else if { ... }
    }            
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to optimize this 'architecture'. Also thought about a switch case function but it seems to only compare my ASCII variable to a single integer like:

```
switch (ascii){
     case '8':
         blabla
```

and this is not what I'm looking for because the instructions really depend on the ASCII variable which is sorted by intervals of 32 ​​which themselves must be sorted by intervals of 8 values.

Comment: Instead of using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), perhaps [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) could help you?

Comment: Or if you're supposed to explicitly handle ASCII, but aren't certain that your programs locale character-set is ASCII-compatible, then please create your own character classification functions. It will make your code much more readable.

Comment: the fact is that I'm not super friendly with C, like a beginner or whatever, so I don't really know how to properly do that

Comment: What are those magic numbers 17, 25, 33, 41 and 65?

Comment: I use these to make ranges of 8

Comment: Do something like `if (isdigit(ascii)) { /* handle digits */ } else if (isupper(ascii)) { (/* handle upper-case letters */ } else if ...`. Other arbitrary grouping doesn't make sense for most of the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you need one case for each interval of 8, e.g. 1-8, 9-16 etc.  Try this:

```
switch ((ascii + 7)/ 8) {
case 0: // input was zero
    break;
case 1: // input was in [1..8]
    break;
// ...
case 8: // input was in [57..64]
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, get rid of the `int` and replace it with `char` or `uint8_t`. It seems unlikely that you have a symbol table with negative indices.

Next, you are basically checking if something is within certain intervals. The least ineffective way to do that with if-else is to do so in ascending order:

```
if(ascii < 17)
  ...
else if(ascii < 25)
  ...
else if(ascii < 33)
  ...
```

Obviously the "magic numbers" should be replaced with constants or character literals.

If there are intervals of 8 (that's *not* what your magic numbers give), you can possibly improve performance by doing `ascii / 8` as look-up. Either through a plain switch or perhaps through a function pointer look-up. Example of the latter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void f0_7   (uint8_t n) { printf("%d %s\n", n, __func__); }
void f8_15  (uint8_t n) { printf("%d %s\n", n, __func__); }
void f16_23 (uint8_t n) { printf("%d %s\n", n, __func__); }
... // up to 127

void interpreteASCII(uint8_t ascii)
{
  typedef void(lookup_func)(uint8_t);
  lookup_func* const LOOKUP[] = { f0_7, f8_15, f16_23, ... /* up to 127 */ };

  LOOKUP[ascii/8](ascii);
}

int main (void)
{
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<24; i++)
  {
    interpreteASCII(i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

(Some bounds-checking before calling such a table look-up is not a bad idea though.)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by 'optimize'.

- Do you want it to have an as small as possible memory footprint?  Then John Zwinck's answer (or something like that) is probably your best bet.
- Do you want it to run as fast as possible?  Then a lookup table consisting of 128 entries (many of them containing the same value) would be the best approach.
- Do you want it to be as easy as possible to read and comprehend? Then nothing probably beats the solution that you have already come up with.